# Once I turn off debuggingData in angular, is there another way to get the rootscope?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, angularjs-injector

I think having debugging info on by default in Angular will sink large apps. You can now disable this in production:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data

But there are some cases where I do:

angular.element(document).scope()

in order to access the rootScope. Is there another way in angular to get the $rootScope without this debugging feature on?

Comment: Please quote the relevant portions from your link target, in case the link goes dead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `$rootScope` you could do

```
angular.element(document).injector().get('$rootScope')
```

Comment: That's awesome. Now I can hit the injector() to get the rootScope and not use that debugging stuff. Turning         $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false); should really bump up speed!